# Connecting a FireBeetle ESP32 to Arduino

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32

I have a very basic question, because I struggle to upload files to my FireBeetle ESP32 Board.

When I try to upload to the board I get an

```
A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: Timed out waiting for packet header
```

On other boards you have to press & hold the flash button, but this specific board just has a reset button.
What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

The flash button is virtual and controlled by the RTS signal from the computer through the USB port (why are you trying to connect through an Arduino?). It should automatically enter bootloader mode when you go to program it. There should be nothing you need to do.

However, if you *do* want to manually enter bootloader mode, just connect IO0 (*note: not D0*) to GND and press the reset button.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you do not have the right drivers installed. That's the issue I just solved for myself. And it can be easy to think you installed the right driver, when in fact you didn't.

Have you followed the instructions on DFRobot's product wiki?

I'm not sure if you have the ESP32-E or the earlier ESP32-IOT Firebeetle, but here's the link to the drivers mentioned for the [Firebeetle ESP32E](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/FireBeetle_Board_ESP32_E_SKU_DFR0654#target_11) and here for the prior version, the [Firebeetle ESP32 IOT](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/FireBeetle_ESP32_IOT_Microcontroller(V3.0)__Supports_Wi-Fi_&_Bluetooth__SKU__DFR0478#target_4)

But I would suggest double checking which board you have an very meticulously ensuring you have the right driver installed.